# Problemas con funcion Click en jquery y llamada a funcion $get.JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, nodejs

Hola no se como explicar bien mi duda pero voy a hacer mi mejor esfuerzo.

Resulta que tengo creada una API en node.js y quiero interactuar con ella a través de jquery. Es un caso sencillo donde tengo que hacer una búsqueda.
Si implemento directamente la búsqueda en el input como por ejemplo:

```
$("input").on("change input textInput", ()=>{.....})
```

funciona perfecto, pero lo que deseo es dar click en un boton y funcione igual y lo que pasa es que no muestra ninguna info ni los `console.log()`.

A continuación les pongo el código que no funciona. Reitero que el problema esta en el jquery porque la api responde bien.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Search Animals</title>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>

<h3>Find Animals</h3>   
SPECIES: <input  name="species"><br>
<input id="button" type="submit" value="Enviar">

<div id="container"></div>
<script>
    $("#button").on("click", () =>{
        //Captur
        var species = $("input[name='species']").val();
        var query = '?';
        if(species) query += 'species=' + species;
        //Creando la URL
        var url = 'http://localhost:3000/findAnimals/' + query;
        console.log(url);
        //Creando la peticion JSON
        $.getJSON(url, (animals, status)=>{
            console.log(animals);
            var container = $("#container")
            animals.forEach((animal)=>{
                container.append('<p>' + animal.name + '</p>');
            });
        });
    });     
   </script>
   </body>

//-----En el servidor Node.js
  app.use('/findAnimals', (req, res) =>{
  var query = {};
  if(req.query.species) 
    query.species = req.query.species;
  if(Object.keys(query).length != 0){
    Animal.find(query, (err, animals)=>{
        if(!err){
            res.json(animals);
        }else{
            console.log(err);
            res.json({});
        }
    });
   }else res.json({});
   });
```

Comment: Algún mensaje de error en la consola?

Comment: Cual es el output de console.log(url);?

Comment: Este es el consolelog(url) ----http://localhost:3000/findAnimals/?species=Dog. Pero ahora funciona misteriosamente y no creo haber cambiado nada

Comment: MI problema era que tenia los input dentro de un form de esta manera: <h3>Find Animals</h3>   
SPECIES: <input  name="species"><br>
<input id="button" type="submit" value="Enviar">

Comment: Quite le la etiqueta <form> y funciono perfecto. Ahora alguien me puede explicar el porque pasa esto ?

Comment: Donde esta el form?